# Is necessary openCR for a three omni-wheel robot

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, ros-melodic, opencr

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I want to ask if it's worth it to program the robot without openCR for things like odometry, movement, imu, etc?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364588/is-necessary-opencr-for-a-three-omni-wheel-robot/) by [al_ca](https://answers.ros.org/users/55624/al_ca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2020-11-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you do not need the openCR but if you like to drive fast, or realy precise then you need a peace of hardware with an rtos (any bigger mcu) or you program it barematel.

you may look at https://micro-ros.github.io/ to have somethink like ros inside of the mcu.

then it depend witch kind of motor controller you use. if it is a good one you need les realtime
see here https://roscon.ros.org/2015/presentations/magazino-roscon.pdf

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2020-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [al_ca](https://answers.ros.org/users/55624/al_ca/) on 2020-11-02**:
The robot is in an indoor and stable environment, it doesn't need to move really quick (approx 0.5 m/s) and its using three dynamixels and two 2D lidars.

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2020-11-03**:
i think you can start without an openCR

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is necessary openCR for a three omni-wheel robot

No

> I want to ask if it's worth it to program the robot without openCR for things like odometry, movement, imu, etc?

This depends on how you define "worth it".

I'm assuming, you mean [this](http://wiki.ros.org/opencr) with openCR. There are many robots out there that don't use this module. Thus, my answers above.

If you have more specific questions or concerns, please elaborate.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-11-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [al_ca](https://answers.ros.org/users/55624/al_ca/) on 2020-11-02**:
Yes, exactly,
I want to ask what are the advantages of using OpenCR in your opinion?